# Tile WMS vs Image WMS

Tags: wms, tiles, openlayers

In `OpenLayers` 3, there is is `ol.source.TileWMS` and `ol.source.ImageWMS`. I don't know if this is specific to `OpenLayers`, but what are the trade-offs between tileWMS and imageWMS? Is there a performance difference? Other trade-offs?

Answer (score 7):

If used with a WMS source, they're the equivalent of OpenLayers 2's `singleTile` parameter. As [@Tim Schaub](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/252/tim-schaub) described in this [letter](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.openlayers.devel.ol3/1114), the `TileWMS` slices the map, requests a grid of images, then mosaics them together. It gives better performance, then `ImageWMS` (which gets the viewport in a single image), but can generate duplicates of labels (if there is a label defined in the map server's layer configuration, the server sends the label with every requested image, i.e. for every image in the grid).

`TileWMS` also can be used with a WMTS source.

Furthermore, `TileWMS` seems to be a little blurry, maybe a developer knows why.

Map with a `TileWMS` source:

[image: TileWMS]

Same map with an `ImageWMS` source:

[image]

Comment: Is there support for post method in ImageWMS or TileWMS?

Comment: Furthermore, TileWMS seems to be a little blurry, maybe a developer knows why ~ possibly because the tile image is stretched/squashed  slightly, to fit into the grid